DateFormat parseStrict does not fail on incomplete input for year
Why does parseStrict not fail on the input 11/11/1 which does not fulfill the DateFormat pattern requirement of dd/MM/yyyy? I expected that it will fail until 11/11/1111 is inputted. Instead, I see that it is reading the year as 0001. Should we check the length of the string before calling parseStrict or is there a workaround?
try {
  final dateValue = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parseStrict('11/11/1');
  // dateValue is DateTime(0001-11-11 00:00:00.000)
} on Exception catch (_) {
  // I expect to reach this line but it is not throwing Exception.
  print("parseStrict fails");
}



I believe yyyy accepts 1-4 digits generously.

Looking at the documentation it does mention If the year pattern does not have exactly two 'y' characters, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern 'MM/dd/yyyy', '01/11/12' parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D. so I guess it is the intended behavior. I suppose you will need to check the length of the strength for what you want

Just a matter of a proper regex.  Or a petitparser grammar. :)
